# Laravel APP_LOCALE en español

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

En Laravel 5.4,  en el `.env` tengo:

```
APP_LOCALE=es
APP_FALLBACK_LOCALE=en
APP_LOCALE_PHP=es_US
```

y en `config/app.php` tengo:

```
'locale' => env('APP_LOCALE', 'es'),
'fallback_locale' => env('APP_FALLBACK_LOCALE', 'en'),
'locale_php' => env('APP_LOCALE_PHP', 'en_US'),
```

Pero quiero dejar en español, ya que por ejemplo si en un controlador uso:

```
$fecha = date('d F Y', strtotime($data->created));
```

`$data->created` es un string que viene de la base de datos, de las columna `created_at`. Me la arroja como:

```
14 August 2017
```

¿Cómo hago para que aparezca en español?

a los APP_LOCALE es probado todos con `es`, guardo, hago `php artisan config:cache` (ya que estoy haciendo cambios en la config) pero sigue apareciendo en inglés la fecha.

Comment: Revisa este post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29524297/laravel-5-config-locale-does-not-works espero que te sirva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes configurarlo usando Carbon. Puedes seguir esta guía para configurar Carbon para esto:

[Laravel - configurando Carbon multi  idioma](https://laraveles.com/laravel-espanol-configurando-carbon-multi-idioma/)

suerte

Comment: Sí, gracias, lo hice con `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES.UTF-8');
Carbon::setLocale('es');
$mydate = Carbon::parse($data->created)->formatLocalized('%d %B %Y');` elijo la respuesta como correcta ya que fue lo que había hecho.

Comment: @pmirnd estoy probando tu código pero siempre me pone el nombre del mes en inglés :'(